# Existence of a maximum matching such that v is un-saturated

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Ture or False: for every graph G without a perfect matching and every vertex v of G there is a maximum matching M of G such that v is M-unsaturated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $P_3$, the path graph on 3 nodes. It does not have a perfect matching but two maximal matchings (by picking either of the two edges present in $P_3$) neither of which leave the center vertex unsaturated.